# Como enviar meu login e senha via $.ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, http, header

Olá, tenho um link aonde ele abre uma janela modal (como se fosse um "alert") para digitar o login e senha.
Estou usando jQuery, a função $.ajax{} para ser mais especifico. Gostaria de saber como faço para enviar no header dele o meu login e senha. Que tipo de comando devo usar? Authentication? Como?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Na [documentação do .ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) encontra algumas opções.

Pode usar o `beforeSend` onde eles aconselham a setar os headers. Exemplo:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    beforeSend: function (request) {
        request.setRequestHeader("Chave", 'valor');
    },
```

Ou pode usar o `headers`. Exemplo:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'meuSite.com/pasta',
    headers: { 'meu-header': 'valor ou senha' }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$.ajax({
    url:'link.php',
    username:'USR',
    password:'PWD', 
    success: function(completo){
        $('#resultado').html(completo);
    }
});
```

Utiliza isto se a autenticação for realmente HTTP, caso contrário defina os valores num campo `data:`.

Answer (score 0):

Oi, você pode usar isso:

```
var username = $("#username").val();
var password = $("#password").val(); 

$.ajax({
    url: "teste.php",
    headers: {"Header-Teste": username, "Header-Teste2": password},
    success: function(data) { alert('Successo!' + data); }
    error: function () { alert('Erro!'); },
});
```

Comment: Como posso fazer ele identificar o login e senha? Pois ele pede 2 (usuário e senha) e com esses códigos me parece que só da para mim colocar, por exemplo "usuário"

Comment: Não entendi direito, mas editei a resposta e coloquei 2 valores no header, é isso ?

Comment: dá uma olhada aqui: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507234/how-to-use-basic-auth-and-jquery-and-ajax

Comment: Sim, mais ou menos isso. Só gostaria de saber como fazer ele inseri o login no campo de "login" e de senha na "senha". Pois ele tem que ter a autorização para entrar no painel de administração e para ter autorização ele precisa informar esse login e senha

Comment: adicionei no cód. 2 variáveis com o valor dos campos...

Comment: Com isso eu posso estar logando em um sistema externo que pede login e senha? tenho o meusite.com e queria logar em seusite.com daria certo? autenticA?

Comment: dá uma olhada aqui: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: eu dei uma lida, só que não entendi como faz a autentificação

Comment: Olá, se for HTTP define no ajax o `username` : e `password:` que são campos para autenticação HTTP.

Comment: Eles pedem meu token, eu informo eles para autenticar só que me retorna no chrome erro 401 Não autorizado